# Did the first known Jedi come from Tatooine?

Tags: star-wars

I was surfing Wookieepedia and on the [Jedi apparel](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Jedi_apparel) page I noticed one line that indicated that it has long been theorized that the first known Jedi came from Tatooine... This seems astonishing, yet I couldn't find any source to back this up.

Is there any known canon to back this up? If so then it seems the Force picked Tatooine as its nexus for the focus of the Jedi. The Chosen one grew up on Tatooine, Luke Skywalker was raised on Tatooine and started the New Jedi Order. And, yet the Jed'daii started on Tython.

Comment: I doubt it's true....

Comment: There is no such a thing as a "first" Jedi: the order was created by a council of force-sensitive scholars and warriors, most probably on Typhon.

Comment: Well, out-of-universe, the answer is "Yes: Luke Skywalker".

Comment: Anybody can edit Wookiepedia. That means it is not a canon source. Unless the article provides links to a canon source, its claims are doubtful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was [wherever the survivors of the conflict on Tython went](https://www.swtor.com/holonet/planets/tython).  That was immediately pre-Jedi (according to SWToR, and I don't know of anything that conflicts).

Answer (score 2):

You are correct: The *Force Storm* comics would be considered C-Canon, or continuity Canon, and is unlikely to be overruled by anything other than T (televised) or G (George Lucas) Canon, which covers the movies.

As the Wookieepedia article is unsourced, and as with most fan wikias is unreliable at best as anyone can hypothesize on there, that page is not even considered S (secondary) but N (Non) Canon.

[See here for more about starwars Canon.](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Canon)

Tython is the original planet.

Comment: Are you saying "G" stands for George Lucas? I always thought it stood for Gospel.

Comment: It's what George Lucus considers Canon, ie the movies and anything confirmed by him. Anyway that's what I thought the article said.

Comment: Indeed it does. OK! I was going by, for instances, sites like [this](http://swtorhub.com/lore-old-republic-star-wars-canon) that say "**G-canon** - This is the top level of canon, the absolute gospel" and so on. So thanks for putting me right.

Comment: @MrLister - There's never been an official confirmation of what G stands for AFAIK from Leland Chee, merely what is and what isn't canon. "George" is an incredibly logical, valid speculation though. BTW, Lucas isn't the one who came up with the terms or specific ideas for canon levels.

Answer (score -1):

This may be irrelevant to your question, but if it helps..... The Sith race on Korriban were force users long before the jedi were created on Tython... So if you are asking if where the first jedi where from, then it's tython. However, if you are asking where the first force users were from, then it's korriban.

Comment: Not true! Rakata used the force long, long before there was any life on Korriban.